# How to add extra field in the ManyToMany generated table with FluentNHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have 2 entities Users and Colors. One user may be associated with multiple colors, and one color may be associated with multiple users. 
I use FluentNHibernate autopersistence model to generate the database. Now I have to add to the generated table UserToColor(UserId,ColorId) also an extra field 'CreatedOn', how can I accomplish and is this accomplishable with fluent-nhibernate?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166426/additional-fields-in-nhibernate-many-to-many-relation-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't support this.  The best workaround is to create an extra class as a link table, and have a many to one relationship to it from each of your existing classes.