# Fluent NHibernate Many to Many Mapping

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a scenario in which i got 2 tables, and a third bridge table for many to many relationship.

Table A:

- AID
- AName

Table B:

- BID
- BName

TableAB

- AID
- BID
- Allow

I have extra field in bridge table how to map many to many in this scenario.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to create an entity for the bridge table!

Look here:

[additional fields in NHibernate many-to-many relation tables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/166426/735864)

**update**

I also found this workaround but I've not tested it:

[Nhibernate many-to-many with extra fields in the join table](http://thesoftwaresimpleton.blogspot.com/2010/03/nhibernate-many-to-many-with-extra.html)

Comment: Actually the scenario is i have Roles table and modules table and the relation between these table is many to many , i have an entity name 'Allow' in bridge table to to enable disable the module access anytime

Comment: ahan Thanks... let me give it a try